# How to include directory structure in an ant jar file?

Tags: ant, jar

I am a bit of an ant newbie, and I'm having trouble making a jar correctly. As an example, say I want to make a jar with my StringUtil class. Using the following ant directive, I can create the jar, but the problem is that the directory structure is lost. It simply puts StringUtil.class in the base directory of the jar. How can I correct this ant directive so that StringUtil.class is inside the com/test directory in the jar?

```
<jar destfile="myjar.jar" >
  <fileset file="${build}/com/test/StringUtil.class"/>
</jar>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to tell Ant to build the jar from the base directory, then tell it to include only the desired file.  Like so:

```
<jar destfile="myjar.jar" >
  <fileset dir="${build}" includes="com/test/StringUtil.class"/>
</jar>
```

Here's the doc for [`<fileset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) tags.