# Create directory structures during Ant jar task

Tags: java, ant, jar

I want to create a jar with the following directory structure:

```
thejar.jar/
    classes/ --> where all classes go
    lib/ --> where all dependencies go
    res/ --> where all non-classpath resources go (scripts, etc.)
    META-INF/
```

Here's my ant task:

```
<jar destfile="dist/main/thejar.jar">
    <!-- Create the manifest -->
    <manifest>
        <!-- JAR should be sealed. -->
        <attribute name="Sealed" value="true" />
    </manifest>

    <!-- Copy main build directory to classes/ directory in JAR. -->
    <fileset dir="dist/main/classes" includes="build/main"/>

    <!-- Copy main library directory to lib/ directory in JAR. -->
    <fileset dir="dist/main/lib" includes="lib/main"/>

    <!-- Copy main resources directory to res/ in JAR. -->
    <fileset dir="dist/main/res" includes="res/main"/>
</jar>
```

If I am understanding this correctly, it should be:

- Copying all the built (.class) files in `build/main` to `dist/main/classes`
- Copying all `lib/main` dependencies to `dist/main/lib`
- Copying all `res/main` files to `dist/main/res`
- JARring up `dist/main/*` into `thejar.jar`

The JAR task executes without errors, but when I go to view the contents of `thejar.jar` I just see META-INF/ (none of the subdirectories I mentioned above).

What's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you saying you want a jar to contain other jars?

Comment: I want my JAR to contain all of its dependencies (which would go in the lib/ directory). But thats only one-third of my question. I also want a res/ and classes/ directory.

Comment: you know that's not common practice, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include directory structure in an ant jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364531/how-to-include-directory-structure-in-an-ant-jar-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `jar` task to copy files in `build/main` into jar's `dist/main/lib`, but

```
<fileset dir="dist/main/classes" includes="build/main"/>
```

means to pack files in `dist/main/classes/build/main` into the jar file.

Take a look at the example from the Ant-Jar task doc:

```
<jar destfile="${dist}/lib/app.jar">
    <fileset dir="${build}/classes"
             excludes="**/Test.class"
    />
    <fileset dir="${src}/resources"/>
</jar>
```

> (The code above) jars all files in the ${build}/classes directory and also in the ${src}/resources directory together into a file called app.jar in the ${dist}/lib directory.

To achieve your request, I think you can copy the classes, resources and dependencies with `<copy>` task into the directory structure that you want and then jar the directory.