# How can I add entire directory to jar using ant?

Tags: ant, jar

I am newbie to ant and I want to include entire directory to the jar file which is creating using ANT ?  Can anyone give a idea for me. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to include directory structure in an ant jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/364531/1164465)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Jar Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) documentation? It has a lot many examples that would be helpful to you. A very short example might me like this:

```
<jar jarfile="${dir.dist}/jarfile_name.jar">
      <fileset dir="${dir.build}" 
               includes="**/*.class"
               excludes="**/UnitTest*.class"/>
      <fileset dir="${dir.src}"
               includes="**/*.properties"/>
</jar>
```

[Here's an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Ant/Jarwithincludesandexcludesusingfilesets.htm) from java2s